# Understanding some Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I came across this Javascript snippet:

```
var sum = +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
```

This example evaluates to 36.

What is happening here and what's the best way to understand/read it?

Comment: Sanity is when you don't try to understand that kind of stuff. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!!` is a way to convert to a Boolean being either `true` or `false`. A numerical representation for `true` is `1` and for false it's `0`. So for example:

`!![] => true => 1`

When you convert `+[]` to a number it goes to `0` (when converted to a Boolean it's false), so `!+[]` is `true`. Now lets convert those items:

```
var sum = +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));

var sum = +((true + true + true + []) + (true + true + true + true + true + true));

var sum = +((3 + []) + (6));
```

Now note `(3 + []) => "3"`, evals to a string. Then the string is concatenated with the number `6`:

```
var sum = +("3" + 6); // "36"
```

Then finally the `+("36")` turns the string into a number:

```
var sum = 36;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three major things to undertand in this particular example:

1. What is the nature and behavior of the unary + operator
2. What is the nature and behavior of the logical NOT operator
3. How the aforementioned operators interact with empty arrays

The [*unary + operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) converts its operand (the value to its right) to a number. The [logical NOT operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9) either converts its operand to a boolean, or *flips* the value if the operand is *already* a boolean.

Both of these operators initially [get the value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) of the operand before doing anything. So when the operand is an array, we need to understand what the *value* of the array is.

Lets try a few things first to explore how these operators behave with an array:

```js
+[]; // 0
![]; // false
```

The `+` operator gets the value of its operand, and then converts that to a number. The `!` operator gets the value of its operand, and then converts that to a boolean.

What if we were to use the `!` operator twice, and use the `+` operator on *that* resulting value?

```js
 !![]; // true
+!![]; // 1
```

Now we're seeing the ability to create both the number 0, and the number 1. Given this power, we can begin to do some arithmetic (note that I am using the grouping operator for legibility:

```js
(+!![]) + (+!![])
```

This results in `1 + 1`, equaling 2. Performing operations like these enough to achieve `36` would require quite a bit of clutter, but the example above leverages the [*Addition Operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) as a short cut.

The addition operator performs string concatenation, as well as numerical addition. So `"foo"+"bar"` returns *"foobar"*. Likewise, numbers in string-form will be concatenated, rather than added: `"3"+"6"` returns *"36"*. The code provided in the question achieves number to string conversion by leveraging the inherent behavior of arrays:

```js
["Hello"].toString(); // "Hello"
[].toString(); // ""
```

With the addition operator, if any side of the operand is a string, the result will also be a string (see step 7 of [11.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)). Because the array's `.toString` method is called, the array produces an empty string. When this string is *added* to a type of number, a string of *that* number results:

```js
7 + ""; // "7"
```

This can be leveraged to concatenate, rather than add, two numbers. In the following example, I adopted our previous code that resulted in `2`, and added a couple more grouping operators for legibility:

```js
( ( +!![] ) + [] ) + ( ( +!![] ) + [] ) // "11"
```

On the left-hand side of the middle `+` operator we generate the number one, and add it to the string produced by an empty array. We then do the same thing to the value on the right-hand side of the middle `+` operator. The result, two strings with the value `"1"`. The middle operator then concatenates these two strings, yielding `"11"`.

Given this knowledge, you should be able to revisit the code in your question, and quickly make sense of the individual portions.